# Error with generics in type constraint in TypeScript

Tags: generics, typescript

I've created a short sample code to demonstrate the problem I'm facing:

```
class List<T> { }

class StringList extends List<string> { }

class NumberList extends List<number> { }

class Iterator<T extends List<any>> {
    list: T;

    constructor() {
        this.list = new StringList();
    }
}
```

[(on playground)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20List%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Aclass%20StringList%20extends%20List%3Cstring%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Aclass%20NumberList%20extends%20List%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Iterator%3CT%20extends%20List%3Cany%3E%3E%20%7B%0A%09list%3a%20T;%0A%0A%09constructor%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09this.list%20=%20new%20StringList%28%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)

This code results in `Cannot convert 'StringList' to 'T'`.

Any idea why and how to avoid it?
Thanks.

---

## Edit

Here's an example of why it's wrong (thanks to @RyanCavanaugh for pointing it out):

```
var iterator: Iterator<List<any>> = new Iterator<NumberList>();
```

Where you'd expect `iterator` to have list of type `List<number>` but the ctor tried to assign `List<string>` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error because it's wrong:

```
class MagicList extends StringList {
    magic = 'shazam';
}

var x = new Iterator<MagicList>();
console.log(x.list.magic); // x.list does not have member 'magic'
```

Remember that a constraint only establishes a *lower* bound on the generic type.

Comment: Well yeah, it's pretty obvious ha?  Now I feel retarded. Your example wasn't dead on (for one thing you did not put `magic` on the list member, just added a member, so you have `x.magic`) but I got the point and edited my question with an example. Thanks!